# How can I apply For each loop over controller object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am having trouble in using Angular foreach loop which where i am getting Undefined value when i try to access please suggest how can i make it possible to use below code so that i can access the value and store it to the $rootScope

```
patientsService.getChartData({  filter:$scope.patientid }).success(function (result) {
                    $scope.chartdata = result.items;
                    alert("success");
                    angular.forEach(result.items, function (item) {

                        alert(item.Image);
                        if (item.TeethNO == 1) { $rootScope.tooth1 = item.Image; }
                        if (item.TeethNO == 2) { $rootScope.tooth2 = item.Image; }
                        if (item.TeethNO == 3) { $rootScope.tooth3 = item.Image; }
                        if (item.TeethNO == 17) { $rootScope.tooth17 = item.Image; }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Entity of the values are:

```
public  int PatientID { get; set; }
            public  int TeethNO { get; set; }          
            public  string Image { get; set; }           
            public  string Description { get; set; }
```

Comment: "i am getting Undefined value when i try to access " - You need to be more specific about this. What is exactly the error? Is result.items undefined?

Comment: When i use this inside foreach loop " alert(item.Image);" then it gives undefined but it should give the value stored in the database.

Comment: On Chrome: open dev tools, go to network, look at the request which should deliver the data, check if the required data is there. Or just console.log(item) to see what is in there.

Comment: Do you get alert for `alert("success");`?
Do `console.log(result.items);` to check if valid entires are received in your service.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer through console.log(result.items); Actually in the result i get over the view first letter becomes automatically and then i changed the    alert(item.Image); to   alert(item.image); 
Thank You All for your support